# zend_rest + mysql + backbone

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, backbone.js, crud, zend-rest

I implemented a *RESTful* application with **Zend_Rest** that saves info in a **mysql** db.
I'm going to handle the view with **Backbone.js**.

I'm looking for just a simple *CRUD* example. How to do that?

I didn't found any examples with Zend_Rest+Backbone, and the idea is to create it here, together.

## UPDATE 0.1

**How can I *send* (from backbone) and *read* (in the get/put/delete controller) the parameters?**

CONTROLLER (modules>api>controllers>BackboneController.php)

```
class Api_BackboneController extends Zend_Rest_Controller
{
    public function init(){
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    }
    public function headAction(){
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(null);
    }
    public function optionsAction(){
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(null);
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Allow', 'OPTIONS, HEAD, INDEX, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    }   

    // called from backbone with "read"
    public function indexAction(){
        // get the params
        $resp = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
        // send the same response
        $this->getResponse()->appendBody(json_encode($resp));
    }

    // I can't reach this one from backbone, WHY?
    public function getAction(){}
    // called from backbone with "update"
        public function putAction(){}   
    // called from backbone with "delete"
        public function deleteAction(){}
}
```

VIEW (modules>default>views>scripts>index.phtml)

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({   
    defaults: {   
        text: "default text"   
    },
    url: "/base/api/backbone",
    options: {
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(x, t, e){
            console.log("error: " + t + ", " + e);
        }
    }
});

var myModel = new MyModel();  
Backbone.sync("read", myModel, myModel.options);

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: The intent of StackOverflow is not to have people do your work for you.  You should try making an implementation and then asking questions around specific problems you are having.

Comment: you're right Mike. I'll add what I did and what I can't do.